# Job Deveria falhar porém fica com status de sucesso

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho um Job no qual preciso retornar uma falha dentro da estrutura
no codigo abaixo a coluna "Coluna" n existe, logo vai entrar no catch

```
   public function handle()
    {
        try {

            Profile::where('Coluna', 'teste')->get();

        } catch (Exception $exception) {

            throw $exception;
        }
    }
```

nesse caso quando vou rodar os comandos

```
php artisan schedule:run
php artisan queue:work
```

ele me retorna isso e fica so tentando processar o job  (loop infinito)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

caso eu remova o

```
throw $exception;
```

ele retornar com sucesso, mesmo passando pelo catch

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon) ele mostra com status como sucesso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém deveria vim como status de falha...

gostaria de saber por q o laravel n entende como erro e como setar ele como falha no laravel horizon?

Answer (score 1):

Existe um erro conceitual de sua parte: o Job não vai retornar uma falha, pois ele foi **executado corretamente**.

Se você retorna uma string, booleano ou uma Exception – o sistema de filas (Queues) entende que fez seu trabalho corretamente, uma vez que a execução não parou por algum motivo.

Outro erro grave: você não pode fazer um throw desta forma.

1. A sintaxe está errada. O correto seria throw new ExceptionNameHere()
2. O catch não serve para jogar uma nova Exception. Serve para retornar o erro em si: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

---

Para forçar uma falha no Job, você pode consultar esta seção na documentação do Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#failed-job-events